# Cannot assign value to ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, dynamicobject

Just trying out on dynamic objects and I encountered this compile error

```
ExpandoObject myObj = new ExpandoObject();
myObj.GivenName = "Testing";
```

> System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for
>   'GivenName' and no extension method 'GivenName' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' could be found

Looking at [MSDN: ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx), they actually did it differently - using `dynamic` keyword

```
dynamic myObj = new ExpandoObject();
myObj.GivenName = "Testing";
```

What is the explanation for this? And is it possible to still assign values on the instance of `myObj` without using `dynamic` keyword? I looked if it has `.SetProperty` but no.

Thanks

### Update

Now I understand I have to use `dynamic` keyword, but what use is this line if it's allowed

```
ExpandoObject myObj = new ExpandoObject();
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to declare the variable as `dynamic` for this to work. That way the compiler will defer the assignment to the `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` part of the variable and the property will be given the value you've specified.

By typing the variable as `ExpandoObject` your specifying an actual type, and because of this the compiler won't use the dynamic aspects of the class.

Answer (score 2):

Once you mark mark a variable as dynamic anything to do with that variable is happens at runtime. So, during compilation, the compiler is not aware of a property `GivenName` as it is not present in the type `ExpandoObject`. But when you declare it as dynamic the compiler will not worry about this variable and the binding happens at runtime.

You can find in detail how to implement a dynamic type at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff800651.aspx